# Get addition of tow time in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get Addition with tow time.

Start Time - 08:30:00

Addition Time - 04:45:00

i want to get 
New Time - 13:15:00

How can i do that in sql server 2008.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype of start and addition time variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @start datetime = '08:30:00'
declare @add datetime = '04:45:00'
declare @result varchar(10)

select @result = substring(convert(varchar(24), convert(datetime, @start+@add, 121), 121),12,8)
```

If your start and added times are not `datetime` values, you need to cast them accordingly first.